# Generación de XML para factura con detracción SUNAT (Perú)

Tags: xml

¿Me pueden ayudar a entender el error? por favor, estoy intentando adicionar la información que me falta para las facturas electrónicas con detracción de **código 027**, me estoy guiando con el Excel que proporciona **sunat**, sin embargo, en el apartado de "Información adicional - detracciones - servicio de transporte de carga" me indica que debo agregar una serie de etiquetas con sus atributos y hasta allí creo que lo estoy haciendo bien, pero me sale que hay un "error al validar XSD"

> Error 1871: Element '{urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2} Delivery': This element is not expected. Expected is one of ( {urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2}DeliveryTerms, {urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2}SubInvoiceLine, {urn:oasis:names:specification:ubl:schema:xsd:CommonAggregateComponents-2}ItemPriceExtension ). Linea: 6 Columna 0

la parte del XML donde estoy ingresando las nuevas etiquetas es dentro de cada ítem, aquí dejo un ejemplo, eliminé varias etiquetas de precio para que el código no saliera tan largo y puedan apreciar donde es que lo estoy agregando

```
<cac:InvoiceLine>
    <cbc:ID>1</cbc:ID>
    <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="NIU" unitCodeListID="UN/ECE rec 20" unitCodeListAgencyName="United Nations Economic Commission for Europe">1.0000</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
    <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="PEN">84.75</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
    <cac:Price>
        <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="PEN">84.7457627119</cbc:PriceAmount>
    </cac:Price>
    <cac:Delivery>
        <cac:Despatch Instructions="Detalle del viaje">
            <cac:DespatchAddress schemeName="Ubigeos" schemeAgencyName="PE:INEI">
                <cbc:ID>000000</cbc:ID>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line>DIRECCION ORIGEN</cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
            </cac:DespatchAddress>
        </cac:Despatch>
        <cac:DeliveryLocation>
            <cac:Address schemeName="Ubigeos" schemeAgencyName="PE:INEI">
                <cbc:ID>000000</cbc:ID>
                <cac:AddressLine>
                    <cbc:Line>DIRECCION DESTINO</cbc:Line>
                </cac:AddressLine>
            </cac:Address>
        </cac:DeliveryLocation>
        <cbc:ID>01</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cbc:ID>02</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:Amount>
        <cbc:ID>03</cbc:ID>
        <cbc:Amount currencyID="PEN">0.00</cbc:Amount>
    </cac:Delivery>
</cac:InvoiceLine>
```